# OpenGL doesn't draw anything if I use PIL (or PyPNG) to load textures

Tags: python, python-3.x, opengl, python-imaging-library, textures

I have a program that uses OpenGL to draw a cube, and I wanted to add textures to the cube. I'm following [this](https://github.com/jcteng/python-opengl-tutorial) tutorial, and my texture loading code is pretty much copied from there. Whenever I call `load_texture()`, any OpenGL calls after that seem to fail without any errors being thrown. Are there any known issues that could cause Pillow and OpenGL to behave oddly when working together? Most tutorials I could find use Pillow, so I think there has to be a workaround.

Here is my texture loading code:

```
from OpenGL.GL import *
import gl_debugging as debug
from PIL import Image

# loads a texture from an image file into VRAM
def load_texture(texture_path):
        # open the image file and convert to necessary formats
        print("loading image", texture_path)
        image = Image.open(texture_path)
        convert = image.convert("RGBA")
        image_data = image.transpose(Image.FLIP_TOP_BOTTOM ).tobytes()
        w = image.width
        h = image.height
        image.close()

        # create the texture in VRAM
        texture = glGenTextures(1)
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture)

        # configure some texture settings
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT) # when you try to reference points beyond the edge of the texture, how should it behave?
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT) # in this case, repeat the texture data
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR) # when you zoom in, how should the new pixels be calculated?
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR) # when you zoom out, how should the existing pixels be combined?
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_BASE_LEVEL, 0);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAX_LEVEL, 0);

        # load texture onto the GPU
        glTexImage2D(
                GL_TEXTURE_2D,    # where to load texture data
                0,                # mipmap level
                GL_RGBA8,         # format to store data in
                w,                # image dimensions
                h,                #
                0,                # border thickness
                GL_RGBA,          # format data is provided in
                GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, # type to read data as
                image_data)       # data to load as texture
        debug.check_gl_error()

        # generate smaller versions of the texture to save time when its zoomed out
        glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D)

        # clean up afterwards
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0)

        return texture
```

Comment: How exactly does the code work *without* loading the images? What do you use for textures in that case?

Comment: Are you using a copy of the tutorial 02's script? Or maybe you did made some modifications on it? Just asking because it's very easy to mess up on OpenGL rendering if you forgot to add an instruction or two.

Comment: As an aside, `convert = image.convert("RGBA")` doesn't cause `image` to change (that's why there's a return value), and nothing in your code appears to make use of `convert` after that.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel, I think that's the issue here. On the texture loader of the repository, this is how its written on this instruction: `glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0,GL_RGB, self.width, self.height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, self.buffer)`. See it? It loads a RGB, not a RGBA file. So the script's author did use convert, but as he didn't use the new image, it probably loaded as a RGB to skip the errors.

Comment: That seems, though, like it ought to just cause the texture to be corrupted (and, perhaps, taken partially from unrelated memory), not for OpenGL calls to fail.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel the code never uses the texture, that's why I think it's to do with Pillow calls breaking OpenGL somehow. I've tried commenting out every GL call in `load_texture` and the problem persisted. I then tried completely removing texture loading and replacing it with one call to `PIL.Image.open()` and the same problem occurred. I suspect Pillow uses some kind of GPU calls internally, but why would that cause OpenGL to break?

Comment: "the code never uses the texture,"  What exactly do you think `glTexImage2D` is doing? " I've tried commenting out every GL call in load_texture and the problem persisted." Including `texture = glGenTextures(1)`? I would expect that to cause a different problem, namely a `NameError` when trying to `return texture`.

Comment: Yes, it loads the texture into memory, but it's never accessed after that. My shader never uses the texture, and it's never passed to it either. Also, I replaced `return texture` with `return -1`, as it doesn't matter what it returns as the result is never used later.

Comment: The other potential issue I see here is that `GL_RGBA8` means that *each component* will take up 8 bits; I haven't done this stuff in a while, but I'm pretty sure that implies you want a 32-bit sized pixel data type, not `GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE`.

Comment: If that turns out to be the source of other errors, I can fix it later. Right now my priority is figuring out how to get PIL to stop breaking OpenGL.

Comment: Try this link, it uses numpy to convert the bytes array to uint8. I did not test it, but maybe the `tobytes()` does not convert to a type that OpenGL can read. https://gist.github.com/jawa0/4003034

Comment: Again, the problem is not that OpenGL cannot read the texture data, the problem is that calling `PIL.Image.open()` makes any further OpenGL calls seemingly do nothing, save clearing the screen.

Comment: @Awesomepotato29 There is no problem with the code. Likely the file path is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

There is just one problem with the code. You need to get the bytes from the converted image (`convert`) and not the loaded image (`image`):

```py
from PIL.Image import Transpose

image = Image.open(texture_path)
convert = image.convert("RGBA")
```

<s>`image_data = image.transpose(Image.FLIP_TOP_BOTTOM).tobytes()`</s>

```py
image_data = convert.transpose(Transpose.FLIP_TOP_BOTTOM).tobytes()
```

After that change the code works fine, I tested it.